# MYSQL inventory management design

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know if the design of the database is wrong or my approach to the problem is wrong but i am working in a inventory/shipments php/mysql software

Lets say i have this table for my inventory

```
| auto_inc | id_pro |   name  |  qty | unit_price |
|          |        |         |      |            | 
|    1     |   PA1  |  Paper  |  10  |    100     | 
|    2     |   PA1  |  Paper  |  10  |    200     | 
|    3     |   FO1  |  Folder |  6   |    300     | 
|    4     |   FO1  |  Folder |  6   |    400     |
```

and lets say i have this table for shipments

```
| auto_inc | where_to | id_pro |   name  |  qty |    cost    |
|          |          |        |         |      |            | 
|    1     |  RGUA    |  CF1   |  Paper  |  12  |    ???     | 
|    2     |  SANV    |  PA1   |  Folder |  7   |    ???     |
```

**PROBLEMS:**

1.- if i need to ship 12 papers how do i update the first row to 0 and the second row to 8 in the inventory table.

2.- The cost of the first row in the shipments table should be 1400, how do i get this number to store it.

I was trying to implement the fifo method here, but i don't know how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
<?php
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $hostname = "localhost"; 
    $db = "inventory_db";

    //connection to the database
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $db);

    //Input variables
    $code = "PA1";
    $name = "Paper";
    $qtyreq = 12;
    $where_to = "ABCD";
    //Output variables
    $totalcost = 0;
    $qtyout = 0;

    if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT `auto_inc`, `id_pro`, `name`, `qty`, `unit_price` FROM `inventory` where `id_pro` = '$code' order by unit_price asc"))
    {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            if($qtyreq > 0)
            {
                $batchout = 0;
                $rem = max($row['qty']-$qtyreq,0);
                if($rem == 0)
                    $batchout = $row['qty']; //This means there are no items of this cost remaining
                else
                    $batchout = $qtyreq; //This means there are items remaining and therefore our next loop (within the while) will check for the next expensive item

                $totalcost += ($batchout * $row['unit_price']);
                $qtyreq -= $batchout;
                $qtyout += $batchout;
                $sql = "Update inventory set qty = (qty - $batchout) where auto_inc = ".$row["auto_inc"];
                echo $sql."</br>";
                $mysqli->query($sql);
            }
        }
        $sql = "Insert into shipments (`where_to`, `id_pro`, `name`, `qty`, `cost`) values ('$where_to','$code','$name',$qtyout,$totalcost)";
        echo $sql;
        $mysqli->query($sql);
        $result->free();
    }

    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: A pleasure, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: it works perfect! i have two more question if that's ok.

How can i do it if i want to ship more than one product, i imagine that i will have to add a shipment_id to group the shipment but i don't know how to do it.

with this estructure it is posible to cancel the shipment and return the products to the inventory, or i have to change the approach?.

Comment: A slight table redesign is required if you want to be able to "ship" more than one product in the same "shipment" per say. Cancellation of "products" also needs a bit of a restructure so if a client returned 6 qty of PA1 for example your database design would need to know which `id` in the `inventory` it came from so that it can be reassigned to the correct `inventory` entry once cancelled/returned. I would therefore add 1 more table namely `orders`. Look at an order as shipment package which you want to assign to `shipments` to by linking an `id` in `orders` to `order_id` in `shipments`

Answer (score 1):

Your problems are simple to solve, with update queries, but I guess that doesn't answer your question.

```
UPDATE inventory SET qty = 0 WHERE auto_inc = 1; 
UPDATE inventory SET qty = 8 WHERE auto_inc = 2;
UPDATE shipments SET cost = 1400 WHERE auto_inc = 1;
```

If you are writing this in PHP, you need to create some functions.

One to determine the price based on the amount in stock. Order by the unit price to get the cheapest ones out first (if that's what you want in your business logic). If you don't have enough in stock of those with the cheapest price, find the next one. Store the ones you are sending out.

Then update the price in the shipment row with the calculated one.

Then update the stock in the inventory.

But if you are writing a bit more complex system, what if a shipment get's cancelled for instance? If you want a cancelled shipment back in stock, then you need to work with unique id's for each product, not with generic one's like 'PA1'. If you have unique id's then you can place them back in your inventory.

Based on your business logic, this can be quite a complex system :-)

Comment: thanks for the inputs, it is really complex to me :S